# How to change battery level in android studio 4.1 emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 4.1 and the emulator looks like this

[image]

Now i am following a tutorial series where the person has old version of Android studio but he is able to change battery level of his emulator using the options provided. The options are accessed by this button

[image]

Now I have right clicked everything. Searched on YouTube but I cannot find this option. So it would be great if someone can guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access that from within the tool window, unfortunately:

[image: A screenshot of the emulator settings panel]

So you'll need to uncheck the `Launch in a tool window` box, and it'll run in a separate window. The tool window version is new so I assume they'll add the options at some point though.

(If you need to find that settings screen, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and type `Emulator`)